# Given a constexpr type_info, can I recover the original type?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

Given a `constexpr std::type_info&`, could I somehow, at compile time, recover the original type to which that `type_info` refers?

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
template <std::type_info& const TYPE_INFO>
using original_type_t = /* implementation here */

struct dummy_testing {};
static_assert(std::is_same<dummy_testing,
              original_type_t<typeid(dummy_testing)>::value);
```

I don't expect that this is actually possible with any currently shipping compiler, but would be happy to be proven wrong.

Now for some background:

I'm working on some variadic template classes that are partially specialized where each argument is itself an instantiation of another variadic template. The full type ends up having N arguments each of which has around M arguments. Needless to say, a single line of compile errors with this class takes up several screen-fulls.

Most of the time, I don't need all the arguments or all of their nested types. I only really need my partial specializations to be unique to a particular instantiation of the top level template. I want to make sure that

```
typename outer<inner<a, b, c>, inner<d, e, f>>::nested;
```

Is unique to that exact sequence of arguments, even when `nested` does not depend on those arguments. It would also help the whole sequence of `inner<x, y, z>` did not get printed for every error. I can find it by following the compile time stack trace gcc gives me.

Alternate ideas and suggestions are welcome. Also, if this were a language feature (assuming that it isn't already), what fun crazy things would YOU use it for?

Comment: No, there is no synthetic reflection facility in C++ (yet). However, people have been getting interested in this subject recently to the point of actual committee work being done in the area.

Comment: No, you cannot "recover" a type from an opaque `type_info`. However, based on your description, you're probably looking for `std::is_same`.

Comment: Why can't something like this work?

`template <typename> struct original_type;`
`template <typename T> struct original_type<typeid(T)> { using type = T; };`

Comment: @Filipp `typeid` is inherently dynamic, it is used for getting the *runtime* type of an expression. That it works with types at all, seems to me at least, is only for symmetry reasons.

Comment: @Filipp: Just to make sure: Do you understand that `typeid(inner<a>) != typeid(inner<b>)`? If you wish to know if two given template instantiations have been made from the same template then you need another technique (involving template template arguments if self-implemented).

Comment: Sometimes you can use inheritance to shorten type names. In a short namespace, you can define `template<class T, T v> struct Val : std::integral_constant<T, v> {};` or even shorter (C++17) `template<auto v> struct Val : std::integral_constant<decltype(v), v> {};`. I understand that this approach is of limited use if you do not know the arguments at namespace scope.